# Distribution of indicator function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ a random variable with pdf $f(x)$. Let also Y=g(X), taking value $1$ if $X>=a$ and $0$ if $X<a$. Then the distribution of Y is Bernoulli right? And the $E(Y)$ is equal to $P(X \in A)$ with $A=[a, \inf)$. My problem is how i can prove these, especially the distribution of Y.

Comment: If by pdf you mean density, then $Y$ has no density.

Comment: I corrected it. Obviously i meant the distribution of Y.

Answer (score 0):

You solve everything following definitions.

By definition, $Y = \mathbf{1}_{\{X < a\}}$ so $\mathbf{P}(Y = 1) = \mathbf{P}(X < a) = p$ and $\mathbf{E}(Y) = \int Y d\mathbf{P} = 1 \times \mathbf{P}(Y = 1) = p.$